# PHP Cookie set and reference doesn't work under include() environment

Tags: php, cookies, include, setcookie

Basically, I'm hitting my head against the wall trying to figure out why a cookie I set refuses to work properly on my dashboard throughout the application. Here are different locations and levels of elevation in which the cookie's info can be retrieved.

Domain.com/login.php 
(Location Where Cookie is Defined)

```
setcookie('GoogleIDCookie',$googleID,time()+3600,'/');
```

../Domain.com/index.php?page=GoogleVoice

--> Loads ---> (Through `include();`)

../Domain.com/dashboardContent.php?page=GoogleVoice

--> Loads ---> (Through `include();`)

../Domain.com/DashboardContent/googlevoice-content.php

At the `index.php?GoogleVoice` level (Where I need it to work -- and where all other included scripts and variables are working, besides this one) I get the following output for trying to set a new variable to the Cookie Variable

```
$googleID = ($_COOKIE["GoogleIDCookie"]);
Notice: Undefined index: GoogleIDCookie
```

However, when I go directly to the php page not used in the include, it works as expected.
../DashboardContent/googlevoice-content.php

At first I thought it was the level of the cookie, but I specified for it to work throughout the domain and appears only to not work when include(); is involved.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check if somewhere you resetting it... strange :(